# Golang,Select, why select deadlock when I add default?

Tags: go

The below code is deadlock.

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    a := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            var (
                name string
                x    int
                ok   bool
            )

            select {
            case x, ok = <-a:
                name = "a"
            default:
                println("default error")
            }

            if !ok {
                return
            }

            println(name, x, ok)
        }

    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        defer close(a)

        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            select {
            case a <- i:
            }
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

a 0 true
default error
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

but when I remove default from select, everything is well.

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    a := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            var (
                name string
                x    int
                ok   bool
            )

            select {
            case x, ok = <-a:
                name = "a"
            }

            if !ok {
                return
            }

            println(name, x, ok)
        }

    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        defer close(a)

        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            select {
            case a <- i:
            }
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

a 0 true
a 1 true
a 2 true
a 3 true
a 4 true
a 5 true
a 6 true
a 7 true
a 8 true
a 9 true

a 0 true
default error
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

a 0 true
a 1 true
a 2 true
a 3 true
a 4 true
a 5 true
a 6 true
a 7 true
a 8 true
a 9 true

Answer (score 1):

When you add the `default` clause to the `select` statement, and if that select runs before the channel send operation of the second goroutine, the first goroutine returns and terminates. This is because with the `default` the first `select` simply selects the default case because the channel is not ready, at which point `ok` is initialized to false, so the goroutine returns. Since now there is no goroutine reading from the channel, the second goroutine blocks, and `wg.Wait` also blocks, hence deadlock.

Comment: oh, yes. I forget default clause return `ok=false` apart from `close(chan)`. Thanks  your answer.